# Amazon WAF + Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf

I was wondering - with both AWS WAF and AWS API Gateway, what are the best practices for choosing which resources to shield with them for max security?

Or is it simply:

1. For all static content - use WAF over CloudFront
2. For all REST api calls - secure it with API Gateway
3. For everything else - secure it with WAF

Kind regards,

Comment: (Via a deleted answer): Direct AWS WAF integration with API Gateway is now available: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-api-gateway-adds-support-for-aws-waf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been liking [placing Cloudfront in front of API Gateway](https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/) so that I can take advantage of WAF globally. Unfortunately you do pay for 2 Cloudfront requests with this solution (api gateway uses cloudfront behind the scenes).

[AWS Shield Advanced](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) is also pretty fantastic (and new) -- once again -- you can only leverage it via Cloudfront currently so you'd need to proxy API Gateway to utilize it.